# Как сравнить 4 массива в JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Всем добра. Делаю фильтр в реакте. Собрал 5 массивов объектов. Нужно сравнить их и на выходе получить массив из совпадений. 
Пробовал так, не получается.

Массивы ITEMS,findList,categoryList, metroList, searchList.
В filterSearch надеюсь получить результат.

```
 function search(a, b) {
        const result = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            if (a.indexOf(b[i]) == -1) {
                result.push(b[i]);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }



    const filterFind = search(ITEMS, findList);
    const filterCategory = search( filterFind, categoryList);
    const filterMetro = search( filterCategory, metroList);
    const filterSearch = search( filterMetro , searchList );
```

Comment: вот это не то, что вам надо - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать вам библиотеку lodash (или underscore). В ней реализован метод [intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection)

[Ваш пример](https://codepen.io/perevezencev/pen/JOPdPX)

```
const array1 = ['1', '2']
const array2 = ['3', '2']
const array3 = ['4', '2']
const array4 = ['5', '2']
const array5 = ['6', '2']

console.log(
  _.intersection(array1, array2, array3, array4, array5)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не претендуя на оптимизированный по времени выполнения код, могу предложить применить к одному массиву метод фильтрации и оставить в этом массиве только те элементы, которые найдены в другом методом includes. На выходе получить массив - пересечение этих двух массивов и к этому массиву-пересечению опять применить фильтр с includes в третьем массиве и так далее.

```js
 console.log([1,2,3,4,5].filter(e=>[10,5,3,2,0,9].includes(e))
  .filter(e=>[10,2,0,5].includes(e))
  .filter(e=>[5,3,2].includes(e))
  .filter(e=>[15,2,3,9].includes(e)));
```

на выходе имеем из

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[10,5,3,2,0,9]
[10,2,0,5]
[5,3,2]
[15,2,3,9]
```

пересечение

```
[2]
```

### вариант второй

(не будет работать, когда в одном и том же массиве есть повторяющиеся элементы)
мержить все массивы, делать объект у которого имена свойств - это элементы массива, а значения свойств - это количество вхождений во массивы, потом фильтровать фсе элементы количество вхождений которых меньше, чем количество массивов

```js
console.log(
  Object.entries(
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  .concat([10, 5, 3, 2, 0, 9])
  .concat([10, 2, 0, 5])
  .concat([5, 3, 2])
  .concat([15, 2, 3, 9])
  .reduce((p, c) => {
 if (p[c] === undefined) {
     p[c] = 0;
    }

    p[c] += 1;
    return p;
  }, {}),
  )
.filter(e => {
  return e[1] === 5;
})
.map(e => +e[0]),
);
```

Comment: К сожалению такой вариант не работает

Comment: Почему. Есть какие-то ограничения на массивы?